# ST_contains between two tables returns all results of one table multiplied by the number of results from other table

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have one PostGIS table of `polygons` like this:

`polygon_id | polygon_geom`

And another of `points` like this:

`point_id | polygon_id | point_geom`

I want to find all the points from the `points` table that are within a specific polygon from the `polygons` table. I tried this query:

`SELECT points.point_id 
FROM   points, 
       polygons 
WHERE  St_contains((SELECT polygons.polygon_geom 
                    FROM   polygons 
                    WHERE  polygons.polygon_id = 2905), points.point_geom) = 't';`

I expect 21 `point_id`'s, but instead it gives me the entire `polygon` table with each line repeated 21 times. How can I get just the 21 rows from the `points` table? And furthermore, how can I then assign the `polygon_id` that these points are within to the `points.polygon_id` column for those 21 rows in the `points` table?

EDIT: If I use this query to check if one `polygon` is in another from the `polygon` table, this query works perfectly. So I feel like I'm close but fundamentally misunderstanding something.

EDIT 2: changed `polygon.id` column to `polygon.polygon_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the Where clause. The `FROM points, polygons` syntax gives you a Cartesian join between both tables, ie, it is just syntactic sugar for a ***full outer join***. So, you can use ST_Contains to only return those points that are inside a polygon. The array_agg function will give you all polygons that a point is inside, in the case that there might be more than one.

```
SELECT  
   pts.point_id, array_agg(poly.polygon_id)
 FROM
    points pts, polygons poly
 WHERE ST_Contains(poly_geom, point_geom)
 GROUP BY pts.point_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the answer. My table is pretty big so in order to test this quickly, can I plug in a specific polygon_id to just test one polygon first? Where can I plug that in?

Comment: ` WHERE ST_Contains(poly_geom, point_geom) AND polygon_id = 1`. Make sure you have a spatial index on the polygon table.